# Rails Admin - List, Scope on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-admin

I have categories and articles. They have a HABTM relation. I would like the possibility of listing each category and the articles that have relation to that article in the list view of articles.

How can I accomplish this?

I have tried with scopes, however this require a function?

https://github.com/mathieul/rails_admin

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom method and then include in fields

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :body, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  def category_articles
    output = []
    categories.each do |cat|
      output << cat.articles.pluck(:title)
    end
    return output.flatten.join(', ')
  end

  rails_admin do
    list do
      include_all_fields
      field :category_articles
    end
  end
end
```